# Difference between white and silver printable CD/DVD by Verbatim

Tags: printing, dvd-burning, cd-burning

Are the silver ones exclusively for thermal printing and the white ones for inkjet printing ?
Or is there a silver type for inkjet as well ?
Do you have photos of both type **after** printing ? I've never seen them (can't open them in stores)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to look at the label. Inkjet printable ones can be either white or silver. Also, thermal printable ones are white or crystal. Injet and Thermal printable are not the same.

Here is a [Verbatim](http://www.verbatim.com/printable/) information page to see the different types they make.

Comment: Important to note: inkjet silver printable disks are not available in Europe but in the USA, except for a model that requires a professional printer and might require a special reader. Conclusion: use the standard white surface

Comment: That is good information. You should add it by [edit]ing your question so anyone who reads it will get that info.

Comment: The injet silvers  printed, are similar to printing on a fuzzy mirror.  It has a completly different apperance than the white. While the injet versions of them sucks up the ink the same way, the base surface is more "hologramy"  The picture is transparent.  Very nice for making a specific glassy Look, very bad for reading small text.  I have some prints done with them, but I dont have the rights to post it. I dont think the "effect" would show up well with a scan either.